# Checking differentiability at the origin

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ be given as

$$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
e^{\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}}, & \text{if }\text{ $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$} \\
0, & \text{ }\text{ $(x,y)=(0,0)$}
\end{cases}
$$

I want to check $f$ is not differentiable at the origin. My attempt would be to consider the sequence $\mathbf{x_n} = (\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n} ) \to (0,0) $. But, notice

$$ f( \mathbf{x_n}) = e^{\frac{-1}{2/n^2}}= e^{-\frac{n^2}{2}} \to e^0 = 1 \neq f(0,0) = 0$$

Hence, $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$. In particular, it cannot be differentiable at the origin. Is this a correct approach?

Comment: You have result which says a differentiable function is continuous, so its contrapositive says a non-continuous function is not differentiable so your approach works.

Comment: $e^{-n^2/2} \not\to e^0$, $e^{-n^2/2}\to 0$. Consider $f(x,0)$ to get a feel for how the function behaves.

Comment: You've been too quick: $e^{-\frac{n^2}2}$ does not tend to $e^0=1$, but to $e^{-\infty}=0$.

Comment: Oh that's a creative way to do it.

Comment: Why do you want to check that the function is *not* differentiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of differentiability can be stated in many ways.  The way that I prefer (and usually teach my students) is this:

**Definition:** We say that $f(x,y)$ is *differentiable* at $(x,y)=(a,b)$ if
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}\frac{f(x,y)-L(x,y)}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}}=0,
$$
where $L(x,y)$ is the linear approximation to $f$ near $(a,b)$:
$$
L(x,y)=f(a,b)+f_x(a,b)(x-a)+f_y(a,b)(y-b).
$$
In your particular case, $(a,b)=(0,0)$. Using the definition of the partial derivative, you can show that $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=0$. This means that the linearization is
$$
L(x,y)=0+0(x-0)+0(y-0)=0.
$$
So, you need to check whether or not
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\overset{?}{=}0.
$$
Since in the limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, we can assume $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, this is equivalent to checking whether or not
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{e^{-1/(x^2+y^2)}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\overset{?}{=}0.
$$
Now, this limit is a perfect candidate for checking in polar coordinates:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{e^{-1/(x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac{e^{-1/r^2}}{r}\overset{?}{=}0.
$$
Can you see how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Fischer [commented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686369/checking-differentiability-at-the-origin#comment1439725_686369), for your pair $(\frac1n,\frac1n)$ to approach $(0,0)$, you need $n\to\infty$, which makes $e^{-n^2/2}\to0$. Since that number is the same as the value at $(0,0)$, this does not show that the function is discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

Actually, the function is continuous at $(0,0)$. If you wanted to prove continuity, then you'd have to check more than just the sequence you described (which are only *some* of the points on the positive half of the line $y=x$), but account for (every sequence in) *every* path. If you know about polar coordinates, it can be done in a slick way with them. And if you don't but know how to work with, say, the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition in this can be done more manually that way.

Since the function is continuous, you will have to use the definition of "differentiable" somehow. A multivariate function being differentiable at a point is a stronger condition than merely "the partial derivatives exist", or even "all directional derivatives exist", so if this doesn't sound familiar, you should look up the precise definition.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi(t)=e^{-\frac1{\vert t\vert}}$ if $t\neq 0$. This function is differentiable at $t=0$ (with $\phi'(0)=0$) because $\frac{\phi(t)-\phi(0)}{t-0}=\frac{1}t\, e^{-\frac1{\vert t\vert}}\to 0$ as $t\to 0$ (recall that $ue^{-\vert u\vert}\to 0$ as $u\to\pm\infty$).

Now you have $f(x,y)=\phi(x^2+y^2)$. Since the function $\theta(x,y)= x^2+y^2$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R^2$ and $\theta(0,0)=0$, it follows that $f=\phi\circ\theta$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ (with $Df(0,0)=0$).